# how to read the weather in this picture

Tags: italy, weather-and-climate, rome

First of all, I'm sorry if this question sounds unrelated to this website, but my justification that I am reading the weather of the city that I will visit after tomorrow

It is Rome, between Feb,16 and Feb, 21 and I am trying to see if I need a jacket.

[image]

I don't know how to read these numbers :)

This is the label for those numbers:

[image]

Comment: @Willeke i am madrid where the weather here is good, i also live in portugal where the weather is good too, i can handle some water but not good for makeup :) anyway i have a hat but i dont know if that weather means too many rain and wind or not

Comment: [Looks like you'll need a jacket and umbrella!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TjqAI.png) There are links at the bottom of the page to change your language/country; you may find these helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because interpreting weather forecasts is not the function of this website

Comment: Based on your profile, you live in Milan, but have somehow ended up at a weather site that shows temperature in Fahrenheit.  Look for a Fahrenheit/Celsius toggle, or just go to a different site: if you google "weather in rome", Google will give you the forecast right in the search box.

Comment: @jpatokal i was in Milano

Comment: Sorry but I have to vote to close this as it isn't strictly on-topic for the website. Next time, [You could try asking this type of questions on our Travel chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here).

Answer (score 3):

The second column is probably maximum and minimum temperatures in Farenheit. Most websites have an option to display them in Celsius if you prefer. That means between 15°C in the daytime and 5°C at night - that's coat weather for me at least.

I expect the fourth column is probability of precipitation, i.e. there's an 80% chance of it raining at some point on Wednesday. Wear a coat.

Comment: and the column after that is wind - direction and speed. The last one, as the headings say, is humidity - so it will be damp the whole time, which makes cold feel colder.

Answer (score 1):

How about this forecast, from [weatherunderground.com](http://weatherunderground.com):

[image]

Another forecast, from the aptly named [doineedajacket.com](https://doineedajacket.com/weather/Rome):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see here, a jacket and an umbrella would help you enjoying your stay in Rome!

Second column is high/low temperature expressed in Farenheits degrees. Third one is a general description of the weather. Fourth column shows how likely you are to get some rain during the day. Please note that it doesn't mean that it will rain 80% of the day when it is written 80%. It just mean that when you have those weather conditions, 8 out of 10 times, there was at least few minutes of rain during the day.

Fifth column shows the wind direction and speed. Doesn't look too windy there.

Last one is the humidity percentage. When it is quite humid, it reinforces the feeling to have a cold or a hot weather depending on the temperature, especially with low wind.

Comment: [Umbrellas are useless](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9bUcHXclDI)

Comment: please could you just repeat the wind thing, because i good with rain but i hate so much wind. will it be a lot of wind?